# Is this only a syntax difference `useState()`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

```js
const [val,setVal] = React.useState(0);
```

Sometimes I see this in other peoples code

```js
setVal(()=>val);
```

Does that have any difference from this.

```js
setVal(val);
```

Comment: In this case, it does not make a difference. There is a 'overload' for the `React.useState` function, in which you can pass a arrow function. In this arrow function, you can accept a paramter containing *the previous state value*. Depending on your use case, this might be useful. However, in your example, the 'previous state value' is not being used, so it does not make a difference, and thus is functionally equivalent to just doing `setVal(val);`

Comment: Put simply, no there's no difference. If you want to know which one to use, use `setVal(val)` unless you need access to the previous state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments point out, half the time this syntax makes no difference. Where it does comes into play is asynchronisity. For example, say you have a `setTimeout` call in a `useEffect` and it waits a few seconds and then performs a state update, but while awaiting, the state is updated from somewhere else in the component. If you were to reference the state value in the `setTimeout` callback it would be a stale value and so if you called `setMyState(prevState + 1)` you would be off by 1. However if you use `setMyState(prevState => prevState + 1)` you have accessed the most up-to-date state value.

Also, it is very useful when you don't want to reference the state value in a hook like `useEffect`. Anything included in a dependency array will cause the hook to update and that can produce chain reactions or fire off a `useEffect`. when using `setMyState(prev => prev + 1)` inside the hook, you can avoid referencing the state value itself.